# how to call FlushRequest on elastic search using JavaRestHighClient for ES?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

We need to call flush request on elastic search index(6.2).

how to call FlushRequest on elastic search using JavaRestHighClient(6.2) for elastic search?

Comment: Do you mean refresh?

Comment: this is what i want in RestJavaHighClient (6.2)
FlushRequest request = new FlushRequest("index1");
client.indices().flush(request); i don't find the method available

Answer (score 1):

The flush API implementation in the REST Client is [coming in 6.3.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/28852).

Comment: Use the low level client to call the flush endpoint. Should be super easy to implement.

Comment: I am facing issue using bulk request ..Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [{url}-1.es.amazonaws.com:443], URI [/_bulk?refresh=wait_for&timeout=120s], status line [HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large]
{"Message":"Request size exceeded 104857600 bytes"}

aws using m4 xlarge instance.. its not working even after batching

Comment: It's not related